# How to show completion menu when typing EX-command?

Tags: command-line, autocompletion

When I use MS Windows version gvim, when typing EX-command, I can press TAB then there will show a completion candidates menu.
For example, if I type `:colorscheme` then a space then press TAB, gvim prompts menu like below:
[image]

But when I use Linux version gvim, it just automatically type in one of candidates, no menu shows. 
How to set up my vim configuration to use this completion menu?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I’ll be surprised if we dont have a few questions on this topic already, but a good starting place would be to read `:help wilmenu`. Great question!

Comment: So this feature is called wildmenu, I can set it by `:set wildmenu`. Thank you.

Comment: Please feel free to self-answer what solved your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the answer from @D. Ben Knoble

This feature is called *wildmenu*, putting this line `set wildmenu` in the .vimrc or .gvimrc (_vimrc or _gvimrc on MS Windows version) can turn this feature on.

Typing `:help wildmenu` in vim to check further detail of wildmenu.